# AttributeError: 'ErrorbarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_ylim'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the results of some experiments with error bars. I'd like to be able to set the y limit in the case of results with extreme outliers that aren't interesting. This code:

```
axes = plt.errorbar(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index, chi_square_y, yerr=chi_square_y_error, fmt = 'o')
axes.set_ylim([-.2, .2])
plt.plot((min(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index), max(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index)), (0, 0), 'r--', linewidth = 2)
```

produces this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-794286dd3c29> in <module>()
     18 rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 5
     19 axes = plt.errorbar(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index, chi_square_y, yerr=chi_square_y_error, fmt = 'o')
---> 20 axes.set_ylim([-.2, .2])
     21 plt.plot((min(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index), max(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index)), (0, 0), 'r--', linewidth = 2)

AttributeError: 'ErrorbarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_ylim'
```

How can I set the y limits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the [matplotlib.pyplot.ylim()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim) function.

Your example is not self-contained, so I cannot check that the below code actually works, but at least the mentioned error will be fixed:

```
plt.errorbar(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index, chi_square_y, yerr=chi_square_y_error, fmt = 'o')
plt.ylim(-.2, .2)
plt.plot((min(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index), max(feature_data[feature_data.num_unique[feature_of_interest] > 1].index)), (0, 0), 'r--', linewidth = 2)
```

Comment: Was about to answer but Leon was faster.  One thing I wanted to add: [`errorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar) returns `(plotline, caplines, barlinecols)`, not the axes.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a bounty question I'll try to get a bit into more detail here.

`plt.errorbar` does not return an Axes object (which has the `set_ylim` method), but rather a collection of `(plotline, caplines, barlinecols)`. I suspect you may have expected the Axes object since this is what `pandas.DataFrame.plot` returns.

When working directly with matplotlib's pyplot you have two options:

**Option 1** - use pyplot directly, without dealing with the axes:

```
plt.errorbar( ... )
plt.ylim([-.2, .2])
```

Using `plt` will set properties to the last subplot selected (by default there is only one). You may prefer this method when dealing with a single figure.

**Option 2** - get an axes object from `subplots`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax.errorbar( ... )
ax.set_ylim([-.2, .2])
```

This is may preferred method, partly because it allows setting the figure size without setting it globally in `rcParams`. It has a few other advantages which I won't get into here.

Notice that when using `plt` the method is `ylim` and when using the Axes object it's `set_ylim`. This is true for many other properties such as titles, labels, etc.